# Categorise the number of values in a list

Tags: list, counting

I have the list [5,15,25,27,30,39,45,50,55]

How do I code the categorisation of the values in a list, where the categories are groups of roughly 10 ? such that I get the following result. I have absolutely no clue where to start, and I am only just learning to code.

0 - 9   =1
10 - 19 =1
20 - 29 =2
30 - 39 =2
40 - 49 =1
50 - 59 =2

thankyou

(I did think of something like
if list[1] > 0 and < 10 make Group[1] == 1
list[2] > 0 and < 10 make Group[1] == 2
but this was going to generate LOADS of bulky code )

Comment: Why was this question voted down, please explain ?

"I have absolutely no clue where to start, and I am only just learning to code."

Answer (score 0):

In your example the thing to the left of `=` is a number divided by 10. Accumulate groups in dictionary then:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a=[5,15,25,27,30,39,45,50,55]
b=defaultdict(int)
for x in a:
    b[x//10]+=1

for k,v in b.items():
    print("%d - %d =%d"%(k*10, k*10+9, v))
```

result:

```
0 - 9 =1
10 - 19 =1
20 - 29 =2
30 - 39 =2
40 - 49 =1
50 - 59 =2
```